# Discord.js Bot rate limit

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So i want to upload my discord bot online but i want to prevent users from spamming it's commands.
So let the delay be 5 seconds, if user runs `!help` the bot answers, but if user run `!help` before the delay is expired bot says: `wait some time before using this command again`.
Also i want the delay to work only for message author and not affect other users.
I'm using command handler so is it possible to make something like `module.exports.delay`?

Comment: Check this out https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns

Comment: View this stackoverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432102/discord-js-cooldown-for-a-command-for-each-user-not-all-users
^

Comment: @Dorian349 i saw this but im using a command handler does that mean i have to put this in every single command?

Comment: No you can work with the command handler itself.

Answer (score 0):

to do that you can use timestamps like:

```
let msgTimestamp = [];
if(message.content === "?" + "help") {
    if(typeof msgTimestamp[0] !== "undefined") {
        if(msgTimestamp[0] + 5000 < Date.now()) {
            message.channel.send("Here embed of command help.");
            msgTimestamp = [];
        } else {
            message.channel.send("wait some time before using this command again.");
        }
    } else {
        msgTimestamp.push(Date.now());
        message.channel.send("Here embed of command help.");
    }
}
```

In this coode you use timestamps, you check if the content of the message is eualt to the command you want to use, if the user had already sent a message, the variable which containing the message timestamp is full, you check then if the the typeof of the variable is not undefined and then you check id the timestamp of when the user sent the message is lower than the actual timestamp + how many delay you want!

Comment: Help command is just for example i want it to work for all commands

Comment: then adapt the code to which will be used to each command